# node promise control flow

Tags: node.js, promise

I am using promise in bluebird to send mysql queries and manage the control flow & errors. Here is what it looks like:

```
sendQuery1(..)
.then(sendQuery2(..))
.then(function(results from last query){
    if(rain){
        res.render(...)
    }else{
        /*
          I need to send additional 2 queries here
        */
    }
}).catch(errors);
```

promise chain is very convenient, but I found out the error handling will be a messy if there are multiple subchains inside.

For here I probably need to write the following inside the /* */

```
return sendQuery3(..)
       .then(sendQuery4(..))
       .then(function(..){
            res.render(".....")
       }).catch(error2);
```

Are there any better ways to handle this type of problems?

Comment: Which `nodejs` version are you using?

Comment: What exactly in the problem? How will error handling get messy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will catch the error, there's no problem in your code. Yup it gets messy but you can go with the following approach to keep the code clean and still implement your logic:

```
sendQuery1(..)
.then(sendQuery2(..))
.then(function(results from last query){
    if(rain){
        res.render(...)
        throw new Error('breakChain');  //intentionally throwing error to skip the remaining chain
    }
    return; //will act like 'else'
})
.then(sendQuery3(..))
.then(sendQuery4(..))
.catch(function (e) {
    if(e.message != 'breakChain')   //act on error if it was other than 'breakChain'
        throw e;
});
```

Comment: @pano -  Synthesizing errors for non-error conditions is not a great design pattern and just indicates that you need to branch the chain rather than have just one flat chain.  I've provided an answer that shows how to branch the chain.

Comment: FYI, this will not work: `sendQuery1(..)
.then(sendQuery2(..))`.  That will not wait until `sendQuery1(..)` is done before calling `sendQuery2(..)` and will not allow you to use the results of the first query in the second query.  I know the OP showed it like that, but it's not correct and will not work properly.

Comment: @jfriend00 Quoting your words here, its just a pseudo a/c to the example code from OP. He accepted the answer so I suppose he knows how basics of promises work. If he had a problem, would've asked about it.

Comment: Well, you're repeating obviously wrong pseudo code.  It would be a better answer if it did not do that.  Just because an answer has been accepted does not mean it can't be improved.  Remember, the lasting point of these answers is as a reference to others who come along in the future.  It's not like an answer is done forever once the OP sees it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't exactly see your problem here. When you have a chain inside a chain (which you normally don't, you should check your architecture right there), you can just catch the errors like shown.

I'd advise you use a global (or local) error handler function, and pass that to the catch-function. Therefore, even when you have multiple catches, you can use the same error-handler.

The in my opinion best solution would be to create a "promise chain bypass", therefore using catch to skip certain parts based on your condition. If this is not what you are looking for, please specify your problem.

Comment: Hi NikxDa, Thanks for the quick response. Can you give more details on the "promise chain bypass"? I know a global error handler will work but I still need to attach the error catching to every promise chain including the subchains inside each chain, that's the issue I am struggling with

Comment: A bypass works by intentionally throwing an error, kind of like in Shaharyar's answer. You can then skip the other "then"-parts and jump directly to the catch, from where you can continue. This way, you do not need nested conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel sorry that I can  not choose two correct answers

Comment: Yes!            Merry Christmas!

Comment: Using a global is a very bad suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What you are discussing here is branching of the chain based on some logic condition.  It is generally better to actually branch the chain rather than throw an error just to abort the rest of the chain.  This keeps errors as errors rather than the scheme that Shaharyar proposed of synthesizing an error that isn't really an error.

You can branch the chain by returning a new promise chain from within a `.then()` handler like this:

```
sendQuery1(..).then(function(r1) {
    return sendQuery2(...);
}).then(function(r2){
    if (rain){
        // processing is done, so just render
        res.render(...)
    } else {
        // return promise here to attach this new branch to the original chain
        return sendQuery3(..).then(sendQuery4).then(function() {
            // process last query
        });
    }
}).catch(errors);
```

FYI, since you've only posted pseudo-code, not real code and we can't see which functions need access to which prior results in order to do their work, we can't fully optimize the code.  This is to show an example of how branching works inside a promise chain.  That's the principle you probably want to use.  If you show your real code, we can offer a much more specific and optimized answer.

Comment: To make your code clean enough, you have to take some design changes. Your approach is good but makes the code looks extremely messy just like traditional callbacks. I prefer generators but as OP doesn't know the node version he has, promises seems appropriate.

Comment: @Shaharyar - The OP is just posting pseudo-code so we can't be precise about the exact code.  This is to show how branching works (instead of manufacturing fake errors) and with the real code things can be optimized around how the actual functions you are calling work and whether your environment supports arrow functions, etc...  The point is to illustrate branching as perhaps a better design pattern.

Comment: @Shaharyar - And, FYI if were refering to the style code you have like this`sendQuery1(..)
.then(sendQuery2(..))` as a cleaner way to do it, that will not work.  That will not wait until `sendQuery1()` is done to call `sendQuery2()` and could not use the results of `sendQuery1()` in arguments for `sendQuery2()`.